# Cant upload a boot loader to arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Using `arduino UNO`(mac) i am trying to upload boot loader to the `atmega328` where the chip is on a bread board, and connected to the UNO board `tx-tx, rx-rx, vcc,gnd ,reset` .

So i am trying to upload a boot loader by adding to the boards.txt file `the atmega on a breadboard 8mhz` , and choose it from boards menu.

than when i try to burn boot loader he says after 0 seconds   :

```
did not find any USB device "usb"
```

than i change the programmer from -  `AVR ISP mkii` to-  `AVR ISP`

it starts then, and after 6-7 seconds of try he fails saying:

```
programmer is not responding
```

I dont know what am i doing wrong, i have also tried with a oscillator,or without it, nothing works.
maybe the fact that its a mac has todo with it ?

Answer (score 1):

To access that portion of memory you need to use the arduino as an ISP (in-system programmer).

The use of USB to program an arduino chip is enabled by the bootloader you are trying to put on.

The usual way is to program a chip directly is using an ISP.

Have a look at the setup here:
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Another good resource for an advanced build is this:
How to Build an AVR Development Board: http://youtu.be/ncobWc61wL4
He explains what he is doing as he goes so it is really easy to follow and he talks about the programming process.

Comment: Thanks, this is not answering my question ,of course i know the link you provide, but this is one way, i dont want to use another chip to boot loading my chip, but to program it from the serial directly using the UNO, they show it in there too, and the question was why my setup is not working ..

Comment: Sorry, I though you said you were trying upload the bootloader. Does the target chip already have a bootloader installed and the fuses set?

Comment: the target chip already has a boot loader, but i would like to upload a new one to it, how would i upload a new boot loader to the atmega328, where i only have :UNO ,and one -atmega328  ??

Comment: You will not be able to load a bootloader via the serial lines on the atmega. Additionally, serial by its nature is serial not parallel so you wont be able to communicate on the same serial line to both the computer and the atmega from the uno. If you have a bootloader installed and the fuses set you will need an external oscillator to get any kind of communication going. Can you take a picture of what you have.

Comment: Also, did you buy the atmega chip preloaded? How did the bootloader get on there?

Comment: the chip came with UNO, i have oscillator of course,so if you have 1 chip,with a boot loader, and you want to program another boot loader, how would you do that ?? is there any way without having another chip,or another hardware ?

Comment: To write to the bootloader area of the onboard memory you must use an ISP or an ICSP. To load arduino sketches into the programming area you can use serial after the bootloader is set. It is the bootloader program that talks to the serial lines to program the memory

Comment: ok thanks, so bottom line, how would one program a new boot loader to a chip without having another chip ? do i need another hardware ?  (do i need a boot loader to change the oscillator to 8MHz ? )

Comment: You would need an ISP or an ICSP programmer unit. The video that I posted above shows how to build a dev board that interfaces with a programmer

Comment: You have an Uno though so you can use it as an ISP as shown in the link above the video. There is also a better explanation here: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: Using the Uno i will need to go and get another atmega328 to be on the board, am i right ?

Comment: That would certainly be the best way. If you are using a genuine arduino uno they use an atmega328 or 168 (168 has half the programming space). If you don't replace with that chip you will need to know what you are doing since the pinout could be different and you would run into trouble if the power, gnd, reset and rx/tx lines are in a different place

Comment: Did that answer the question for you? Do you need further help?